# PHP, HTML: Submit form automatically

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a PHP page with an HTML form on it. If some variables are set in the URL I would like to automatically submit the form on the page.

IE:

```
if (isset($_GET['var']))
{
  // SUBMIT FORM
}
else
{
  // leave the page alone
}
```

EDIT:

Here is what I have using the answer that someone provided below, but it's still not working. I would like the form to submit itself if the condition is met.

```
<?php

if ($r == 1)
{

echo "  
  <br>
   <form action=\"bookRoom.php\" method=\"post\" id=\"dateForm\">
    <input name=\"from\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$fday/$fmonth/$fyear\">
    <input name=\"to\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$tday/$tmonth/$tyear\">
    <input type=\"submit\">
   </form>

  <script type=\"text/javascript\">
    $('#dateForm').submit();
  </script>
";      
}
?>
```

Comment: ok, so whats stopping you?

Comment: Not going "there". *"I have a PHP page with an HTML form on it."* – oh? So let's see it then.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** — and **include valid code** to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: i think this is a bad approach, if you have the variables in the url, you don't need the html form at all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Using pure javascript instead of jQuery :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['var']))
{?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('dateForm').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>

<?php 
}
else
{
  // leave the page alone
}
?>
```

Comment: what is meant with `//leave the page alone`. Is there any important code?

Comment: @Adam that was part of his example, it's a copy past

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['var']))
{?>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("formid").submit(); // Here formid is the id of your form
                           ^
</script>

<?php }
else
{
  // leave the page alone
}
?>
```

Comment: native javascript would suffice, no need for jQuery

Comment: Be careful, this only works with a JavaScript framework which accepts `$('#formid')`

Comment: It seems mine doesn't accept it. I apologize for my ignorance but I know very little about javascript. How can I get a framework that supports $('#formid') ?

Comment: @user2018084 Framework?? Buddy It is jQuery a library of javascript well I have edited my answer and converted jQuery to javascript.See my updated answer