# How to submit a form when selected file?

Tags: forms, submit

I have a form

```
<form method="post" action="site_N.xhtml">
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="submit" name="U_submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I used `onchange="this.form.submit()"` but it's not working because my submit button in my form have a name="U_submit"

Please help me! :(

Please tell me how to auto submit a form when selected file with `name="U_submit"` not `name="submit"` ?

Thankyou so much!

Comment: Check this link, if it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18600772/4350275

Comment: Sorry. I mean not use PHP, i don't know php :(

Answer (score -1):

Add this script and give some `id` to your form like below.

```
<script>

        function formSubmit()
        {
            alert('in function');
            document.getElementById("form1").submit();
            alert('after submission');
        }

</script>

<form id = "form1" method = "POST" action="site_N.xhtml">

  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="formSubmit()"/>
  <input type="submit" name="U_submit" value="Submit"/>

</form>
```